# Curved arrowstyle in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to replicate this:
[image]

And I have gotten quite far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


colors = ["#CC5A43","#CC5A43","#2C324F"]

data = {
    "year": [2004, 2022, 2004, 2022, 2004, 2022],
    "countries" : [ "Denmark", "Denmark", "Norway", "Norway","Sweden", "Sweden",],
    "sites": [4,10,5,8,13,15]
}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.sort_values(['countries' ,'year' ], ascending=True ).reset_index(drop=True)
df['ctry_code'] = df.countries.astype(str).str[:2].astype(str).str.upper()
df['year_lbl'] ="'"+df['year'].astype(str).str[-2:].astype(str)
df['sub_total'] = df.groupby('year')['sites'].transform('sum')
no_bars = df.sub_total.max()
sub_totals = df.sub_total.unique()
years= df.year.unique()
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1,figsize=(6, 6), subplot_kw=dict(polar=True))
fig.tight_layout(pad=3.0)

colors = [["#CC5A43"]*4 +["#2C324F"]*5 + ["#5375D4"]*13,
          ["#CC5A43"]*10 +["#2C324F"]*8 + ["#5375D4"]*15]

for sub_total, year,color,ax in zip( sub_totals, years,colors,axes.ravel()):
        angles =  np.arange(0,2*np.pi,2*np.pi/sub_total)
        ax.plot([angles, angles],[0,1],lw=4, c="#CC5A43")
        ax.set_rorigin(-4)
        ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
        ax.set_yticklabels([])
        ax.set_xticklabels([])
        ax.grid(False)
        ax.spines[['polar','inner']].set_color('w')
        ax.text(np.pi/2,-3.2, year,va="center" )
        for i, j in enumerate(ax.lines):
                j.set_color(color[i])

#add legend
color_legend = [ "#A54836", "#5375D4", "#2B314D",]
lines = [Line2D([0], [0], color=c, linestyle='-', lw=4,) for c in color_legend]
labels = df.countries.unique().tolist()
plt.legend(lines, labels,
           bbox_to_anchor=(1.5, -0.02), loc="lower center",
            frameon=False, fontsize= 10)
```

which produces:
[image]

But I am really scratching my head on how to do the annotation "arrows":

[image]

I was hoping that '-(' would work, but it doesnt.

My question is, do I need to create my own arrwostyle for this (good resource for this?) or is there a more obvious way of doing it and I am completely missing it?

Comment: There's nothing that I know of. Perhaps you can make use of Matplotlib's [angle-annotation example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/angle_annotation.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-angle-annotation-py).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot a line on the polar axes to get something like this. But be aware, you can't just define the end points, that will still plot as a straight line. See [How to draw a curved line/arc in a polar plot with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53730598/how-to-draw-a-curved-line-arc-in-a-polar-plot-with-matplotlib) for more info.

So, we can define an array of points between the two angles we want, with a constant radial distance.

```py
for sub_total, year,color,ax in zip( sub_totals, years,colors,axes.ravel()):
        angles =  np.arange(0,2*np.pi,2*np.pi/sub_total)
        ax.plot([angles, angles],[0,1],lw=4, c="#CC5A43")
        ax.set_rorigin(-4)
        ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
        ax.set_yticklabels([])
        ax.set_xticklabels([])
        ax.grid(False)
        ax.spines[['polar','inner']].set_color('w')
        ax.text(np.pi/2,-3.2, year,va="center" )
        for i, j in enumerate(ax.lines):
                j.set_color(color[i])

        # this is what I added:
        angle1, angle2 = np.pi/4, 1.4*np.pi/4
        anglemid = np.mean([angle1, angle2])
        anglerange = np.arange(angle1, angle2, 0.001)
        r = np.ones_like(anglerange) * 2
        ax.plot(anglerange, r, lw=1, c="grey", clip_on=False)
        ax.plot([anglemid, anglemid], [2, 2.5], lw=1, c="grey", clip_on=False)

        ax.set_rmax(1)
```

Note I set `rmax` to 1 to ensure the original plot does not change.

Modify angle1 and angle2 to your required values.

You need to define `clip_on=False` for the lines to allow them to show up outside the plot area (i.e. with r > rmax).

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! I was thinking of creating a thin pie chart but your solution is way better. Appreciate it :)